# Как получать все сообщения с аккаунта?

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Вот документация API вконтакте: https://vk.com/dev

Помогите, пожалуйста, справится с задачей: с помощью скрипта на сайте site.ru/message получать все сообщения с аккаунта https://vk.com/id12345678

Создал приложение ВКонтакте и подключил:

```
<script src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script language="javascript">
    VK.init({
        apiId: 4598444
    });

  VK.api("users.get", {user_ids:"1,2,3,4,4598444"},  function(data) {
    // Действия с полученными данными выводит [object Object],[object Object]
    $('#inp4').html('-'+data.response+'-')    
    });
     function authInfo(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            //console.log('user: '+response.session.mid); 
            //alert('user: '+response.session.mid);
           $('#inp').html(response.session.mid);           
           $('#inp2').html(response.session.mid);  
        } else {
            console.log('not auth'); 
           alert('not auth');
        }
    }
    VK.Auth.getLoginStatus(authInfo);
    VK.UI.button('login_button');
</script>
```

Как вообще что-нибудь можно получить, к примеру, сообщения пользователя?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, читайте внимательно документацию, ссылку на которую вы привели в начале.

[Сообщения пользователя](https://vk.com/dev/messages.get) в браузере — не получить. Эта возможность только для клиентских "Standalone" приложений: мобильных например. Ваш «автомат» — приложение типа «Сайт».

В ответе на `users.get()` возвращается массив объектов, который как "`.html('-'+data.response+'-')`" не вывести.

Разберитесь для начала с простой задачей вывести ссылки на профили выбранных юзеров в виде картинок их профилей. Выполнив её, вы перейдёте на следующий уровень : )